# Display Shopping Cart items as partial view on every page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am building an mvc web application that is very similar to MVCMusicStore. I would like to display my shopping cart items in a little list in the top right corner of the screen, so that the user can see what is in the shopping cart at any given moment in time. I have this in my partial view:

```
@model ProOptInteractive.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
    {

  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">@item @item.Count</a></li>
    }
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

and the partial view in the _Layout.cshtml file is

`@{Html.RenderAction("CartSize", "ShoppingCart");}`

Whenever I run the program i get a Object reference not set to an instance of an object error, pertaining to `@foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)` and even if i copy straight out of the code for the shopping cart index page, I still get this error. The shopping cart won't appear unless I click AddToCart.

Please advise

Comment: Update your question and show us whats in the ShoppingCartViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding a method in my ShoppingCartControlled nearly identical to the Index method, called CartSummary and returning a PartialView:

```
public ActionResult CartSummary()
    {
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        // Set up our ViewModel
        var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
        {
            CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
        };
        // Return the view
        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }
```

This was the only method that appeared to "contain" any shopping cart items. I referenced it through `@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart");}`

Thanks to all for your contributions!